# ZXing Scanner Camera is not activating in UWP and WP 8.1

Tags: xamarin.forms, zxing

I am using the example code from the ZXing page .
Details are :

> Windows 10 Pro N,   Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 ,
>   Xamarin.Forms 2.3.1.114 ,  ZXing.Net.Mobile 2.1.47 ,
>   ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms 2.1.4.7

I am using below code

```
 btnScan.Clicked+=async(sender,e)=>{
    var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage ();
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync (scanPage);
    scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) => 
    {
    scanPage.IsScanning = false; 
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (async () => 
    {
    await Navigation.PopModalAsync ();        
    await DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");
    });
    };        
    }
```

Also I have added the below line in the MainPage.xml file of the UWP project just before LoadApplication method call

```
ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.WindowsUniversal.ZXingBarcodeImageViewRenderer.Init();
```

Also I have provided access to the WebCam from the application manifest.

When I run the application in Debug or Release mode in the emulator then it opens the scanner but small black/white /red /green square comes and computer webcam is not accessed.
When I run it as windows 10 app then nothing comes, only blank screen comes.
When I run it in the real windows 10 mobile, then scanner opens but camera doesn't opens, the white screen with red line opens and camera doesn't activates.
The same thing happens with WIndows 8.1 also.

Any help would be deeply appreciated. I have wasted lot of time to explore the internet used almost every combination. If anyone have the solution please please provide me.

Note:
The above code works fine for Android and I am able to scan the bar code and QR code.

Comment: have you tried calling `ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.WindowsUniversal.ZXingBarcodeImageViewRenderer.Init();` from your **main Page's constructor**, like documentation suggests?

Comment: @nika-gamkrelidze I have already mentioned this in my question. Please read question from start to end.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all options given by users in different forums, but none of them were working.
if you are also facing same issue then please check you camera. If you are using Windows Pro N or KN version, then you have to install the media feature pack to make camera working.

I installed the media fature pack for windows K and KN versions but still it was not working.
When I try to open the Camera App then also it was saying that Media Fature Pack Required for Windows K and KN versions.

Finally I installed Windows 10 Pro version (removed Pro N/KN version)  and reinstalled VS 2015 and tried of of the solution given by user at xamarin forum 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/76035/zxing-scanner-camera-is-not-activating-in-uwp-and-wp-8-1#latest

But still I am still facing this issue for WP 8.1